# Java: What is the best way to check if file needs to be updated before rewriting it?

Tags: java, file, hash

We generate some file in our code. Sometimes the file coicides with the one, we have generated before. A question is : how can we check if the files are the same and skip writing?

The only way I see is:

- read saved file in a string and generate its hash
- generate hash of string we want to save into a new file
- compare the hashes

May be, there are better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, hash is the best way to find modification/updates. Alternatively, if you have a **definite line or character change** whenever there is an update, you can just check that change with the new file generated and decide if you want to proceed with the write operation. You can always introduce such a parameter like a counter when you write a file, but updating the counter will require some logic that is related to the changes made before writing. The answer to this question depends on the context and working of the application.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 Check Sum is the easiest way. I think your approach is valid.

Example I use in a unit test:

```
/** Returns a MD5 checksum from a file
 * 
 * @param filename file name to write
 * @return String
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static String createChecksumForFile(String filename) throws Exception
    {
  InputStream fis =  new FileInputStream(filename);

  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  int numRead;
  do {
    numRead = fis.read(buffer);
    if (numRead > 0) {
      complete.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
    }
  } while (numRead != -1);

  fis.close();

  byte[] b = complete.digest();
  String result = "";
  for (byte aB : b) {
     result +=
             Integer.toString((aB & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: By the way, that method came from old source code. I'm pretty sure there are improved ways of obtaining the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is any easy way to determine whether the data is still uptodate it'll be more efficient to simply overwrite it with the existent data, since reading and hashing a complete file is quite likely to be slower than simply overwriting the data. Though this is highly dependant upon the filesize.

Comment: Probably you are right but I dont want to make an overwrite because this changes the file modification date and makes a confusion this way. I want a file to be modified only if updated.

Comment: Then it's highly dependant upon file-content